# How do i edit files in admin area? (Magento)

Tags: magento

I would like to customize my admin panel visuals.. can i customize it in magento?? if so how do i do it?

Please suggest me basics of this or example links would be helpful..

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: this goes exactly the same as frontend and you can find templates from app/design/adminhtml/default/

Comment: Why do i get a downvote for this question? please let me know what i did wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to follow articles from 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base and of course your mantra would be http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide . Please note that template changing for front-end and back-end is based on same principles

Comment: this is actually balanv's 15th Magento question on StackOverflow...

Comment: he's certainly new to theme changing which is most essential knowledge for any magento dev i guess

Comment: Thankyou Anton and Jonathan... yesterday i tried it out as like customizing frontend theme.. and it worked.. thanks for your support...